# Elementary OS Source List removed and substituted by Ubuntu 14.04 Source-list

Tags: sources

After `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
my `cat /etc/issue` looks like `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l`
and furthermore `apt-cache policy` tells me

```
~$ apt-cache policy
Paketdateien:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-de
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-de
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-de
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-de
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
Mit Pinning verwaltete Pakete:
```

which means the source lists of elementary os got substituted on distro-upgrade...

can i get the sourcelist of elementary os back?

Comment: Here is my sources from /etc/apt  Hopefully it'll help.   https://mega.nz/#F!wghzRZ7b!3TX5523AoRsntOAiI2Hfhg

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fresh set of sources with only a few repositories installed, but they won't affect anything as they just update some programs to their new stable build.  I will add a link to the download as a comment incase it gets caught in the spam filter.