# Can't install repositories in Loki

Tags: release-loki, repositories

How can I add another repositories in Loki?

When I try to install software-properties-common I get the message:

```
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

My system version:

```
root@B400VC:~# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="0.4.1 Loki"
ID="elementary"
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki"
VERSION_ID="0.4.1"
HOME_URL="http://elementary.io/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://elementary.io/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/elementary/"
VERSION_CODENAME=loki
UBUNTU_CODENAME=loki
```

Comment: can you add the full command you are attempting to execute?

Comment: root@B400VC:~# apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
root@B400VC:~#

Comment: You need to run it with the sudo command.

Comment: Nevermind it looks like you are running as root. I missed that.

Comment: apt update runs without problems?

Comment: Without
'root@B400VC:~# apt update 
Fetched 242 kB in 1s (222 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@B400VC:~# apt install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
root@B400VC:~#'

Answer (score 1):

I once had similar problem - my sources where somehow wrong.
Here were the correct ones for LOKI that solved it for me:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list
```

and there...

```
deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial main
```

...next...

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
```

and there

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
```

...next...

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list
```

and there

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this before.

You cannot install software-properties-common until you have first run an update

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

That should do it.

Comment: root@B400VC:~# 
root@B400VC:~# apt-get update           
Fetched 4 840 B in 0s (7 702 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@B400VC:~# apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
root@B400VC:~#

Comment: Hmm... I am not too sure at this point. Maybe your sources got messed up? Here is a link where I posted my sources as a download in a comment. Maybe they can replace yours and get you back to speed. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/elementary-os-source-list-removed-and-substituted-by-ubuntu-14-04-source-list/13253#13253